# Traccar client: hide the app when tracking service started

Tags: android, kotlin, traccar

I'm working on a project where I need to ensure that the Traccar client is not accessible when the service status is 'on.' The goal is to restrict user access to the app and prevent them from closing the service. Has anyone implemented a solution for this or has insights on how to achieve it within Traccar? I appreciate any guidance or suggestions you can provide. Thank you!

For a better understanding, here is the code for `TrackingService.kt`. I'm looking to hide the app when this service is initiated by the user

For more comprehension there is the source code for traccar client [Traccar client android](https://github.com/traccar/traccar-client-android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/org/traccar/client)

```
import android.Manifest
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.annotation.TargetApi
import android.app.Notification
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import android.os.IBinder
import android.os.PowerManager
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock
import android.provider.Settings
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager

class TrackingService : Service() {

    private var wakeLock: WakeLock? = null
    private var trackingController: TrackingController? = null

    class HideNotificationService : Service() {
        override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
            return null
        }

        override fun onCreate() {
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, createNotification(this))
            stopForeground(true)
        }

        override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
            stopSelfResult(startId)
            return START_NOT_STICKY
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("WakelockTimeout")
    override fun onCreate() {
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, createNotification(this))
        Log.i(TAG, "service create")
        sendBroadcast(Intent(ACTION_STARTED).setPackage(packageName))
        StatusActivity.addMessage(getString(R.string.status_service_create))

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean(MainFragment.KEY_WAKELOCK, true)) {
                val powerManager = getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
                wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, javaClass.name)
                wakeLock?.acquire()
            }
            trackingController = TrackingController(this)
            trackingController?.start()
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, Intent(this, HideNotificationService::class.java))
        }
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR)
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent)
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        stopForeground(true)
        Log.i(TAG, "service destroy")
        sendBroadcast(Intent(ACTION_STOPPED).setPackage(packageName))
        StatusActivity.addMessage(getString(R.string.status_service_destroy))
        if (wakeLock?.isHeld == true) {
            wakeLock?.release()
        }
        trackingController?.stop()
    }

    companion object {

        // Explicit package name should be specified when broadcasting START/STOP notifications -
        // it is required for manifest-declared receiver of the status widget (when running on Android 8+).
        // Refer to https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#manifest-declared-receivers
        const val ACTION_STARTED = "org.traccar.action.SERVICE_STARTED"
        const val ACTION_STOPPED = "org.traccar.action.SERVICE_STOPPED"
        private val TAG = TrackingService::class.java.simpleName
        private const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 1

        @SuppressLint("UnspecifiedImmutableFlag")
        private fun createNotification(context: Context): Notification {
            val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, MainApplication.PRIMARY_CHANNEL)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            val intent: Intent
            if (!BuildConfig.HIDDEN_APP) {
                intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
                builder
                    .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.settings_status_on_summary))
                    .setTicker(context.getString(R.string.settings_status_on_summary))
                    .color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.cardview_dark_background)
            } else {
                intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS)
            }
            val flags = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            } else {
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            }
            builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, flags))
            // Set the intent to null to disable launching the MainActivity
//            builder.setContentIntent(null)

            return builder.build()
        }
    }
}
```